# Simplification of a capacitor circuit with nodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, capacitance

If the problem is something like :

**Capacitors of 2 Farads are connected between pair of nodes (a,c),(c,d),(a,d),(b,d),(c,b) and we have to find equivalent capacitance between node a and b.**

Which can be solved using Wheatstone bridge approach :

Ignore diagonal capacitance between nodes and get result = 2 Farads
[image]

But if the question is to be solved using normal approach (Drawing Nodes Linearly)
[image]
How to simplify this circuit (and find that diagonal capacitor) , Is KVL/KCL approach possible ?

Comment: johan lenon - Hi, I recommend you include the schematics for those two options in your question. It seems you tried to include them, there was a syntax error so they didn't display, but then instead of fixing the syntax error (so the images displayed) you deleted the images. I would not have done that, but instead I recommend that you fix the syntax error (e.g. the lines starting `[1]: https:// ...` for each image must have a blank line before that block of lines and must be on a separate line for each number). You are more likely to get replies, if your question is easier to understand.

Comment: Also be sure to include your own attempt to solve the question. (Without seeing an image, I don't yet understand what the question is but, when you make that clear, please show how you are attempting to solve the problem, and show exactly where you are getting stuck.) Thanks.

Comment: You refer to nodes 'c' and 'd' in your question, but there are no such nodes labelled in your schematics.

Comment: c,d can be either unlabeled nodes, but this does not excuse the user from improvement in future for quality of questions

Comment: KVL/KCL **always** applies, but it's a lot of work for something you can simplify intuitively if you draw the circuit in the diamond shape.

Comment: If they were inductors you could do a D-Y transform .

Answer (score 0):

When a bridge is balanced with 0 voltage across the center element, it cannot conduct any current and therefore it cannot affect the capacitance, C,  seen by at the nodes **"a,b"**

When balanced, the center element has no effect on the equivalent C and only affects the C value or impedance seen across the nodes assumed to be "c,d".

The capacitor bridging the two (2) dividers has no effect and so can be removed in this example, so these five (5) capacitors may be replaced by one (1) capacitor of value C.

This can be proven with any method such as KVL but was not shown as this ought to be intuitively obvious after this explanation.

Comment: You had the beginning of a useful answer and then you started talking about sensors.

Comment: @user253751  Ok  I get it.

Comment: also what is source and load impedance in this case? The question does not mention source or load impedance. You can point out capacitance is a type of impedance, but... there isn't source and load capacitance here.

Comment: @user253751 satisfied yet?